# Jquery Datatable data transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I've very new to Jquery and datatable plugin.

I'm receiving JSON data from server and displaying it in jquery datatable plugin.
Data is in the following format:

{"id":1,"name":"Test",**"value1":false,"value2":0**,"value3":1140}

My question is when displaying value1 and value2, I want to transform false to No and true to Yes and similarly transform 0 to No and 1 to Yes.

Is there a way I can do this transformation at client level, without changing anything on server?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the JSON and then change those values just like if you were dealing with a regular JS object. If you have jQuery you could their `$.parseJSON` method.

For example:

```
// $.parseJSON takes a JSON string and turns it into a JS Object
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"id":1,"name":"Test","value1":false,"value2":0,"value3":1140}');

// Changing the definition of value1 and value2 depending on its value.
obj[value1] = (obj[value1] === true) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
obj[value2] = (obj[value2] === 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```